# Incorporating time dependent function into numerical difeq

Tags: matlab

In trying to solve a differential equation shown below

```
function dr = ball(t,b)

T2 = 1;
T1 = T2/2;
d  = 0;
R  = 0.2;

dr = zeros(3,1);
dr(1) = (-1/T2)*b(1)-d*b(2);
dr(2) = (-1/T2)*b(2) + d*b(1) + R*b(3);
dr(3) = (-1/T1)*b(3) - R*b(2) ;

end
```

I did this using ode45.  Now I want to do this where my R is not a function of t.  How would I incorporate this into the differential equation setup.

Comment: I assume you mean `R` is a function of `t`? How is it defined?

Comment: R goes as the sin (t)(times constants)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `t` input, which gives you the current time step, and define `R` to whatever you want.

```
function dr = ball(t,b)

T2 = 1;
T1 = T2/2;
d  = 0;
R  = sin(t); %// for example

dr = zeros(3,1);
dr(1) = (-1/T2)*b(1)-d*b(2);
dr(2) = (-1/T2)*b(2) + d*b(1) + R*b(3);
dr(3) = (-1/T1)*b(3) - R*b(2) ;

end
```